# What is this following C language code snippet doing?

Tags: c

The following code snippet is a part of the program to evaluate a postfix expression. I am not too much experienced with C programming, so forgive me for my lesser knowledge. I do not understand what the highlighted part of the code is doing.

```
char str[100];

int i, data = -1, operand1, operand2, result;

/* Get the postfix expression from the user */

printf("Enter ur postfix expression:");

fgets(str, 100, stdin);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
{

    if (isdigit(str[i])) 
    {
          /*
           * if the i/p char is digit, parse
           * character by character to get
           * complete operand
           */
           data = (data == -1) ? 0 : data;

           data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);   //What is happening here 

           continue;
}
```

Comment: Debug your code and you'll know.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Here is the link to complete code for your reference http://see-programming.blogspot.in/2013/02/evaluating-postfix-expression-using.html

Comment: You're sure there is no redundant star in your code?

Comment: @moeCake Yeah they are redundant, perhaps I have just used the stars to highlight the part I do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code snippet

**data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);

this line will change your string to integer format

for example like you are giving input 235

then ASCII code of 2 is 50 and when you subtract with 48 then it will come 2.
now multiply you previous no (which is 0) by 10 and add 2. then it will become 2
next 3 will come which is having 51 ASCII and after subtract 48 will become 3
now multiply you previous no (which is 2) by 10 and add 3. then it will become 23 and so on.

like this you are converting string to an integer no.

Answer (score 2):

It is converting the number in the string `str` to an actual number, digit per digit (or character per character if you will).

The line

```
data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);
```

takes the number "so far" and adds the new digit to it, by multiplying the number by 10 and then adding the value of `str[i]` to it. The character `str[i]` is in the range '0' .. '9' and by subtracting 48 of it -- the ASCII value of '0' -- you get the value of the digit.

So if `data` is 95; for instance, and `str[i]` is '3', then `data` becomes 950 + ASCII code of '3' - ASCII code of '0', so `data` becomes 950 + 3 = 953.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering. I have one more question, Is this a necessary way to extract numbers from an array ?

Comment: @AkashRana: No, it's best to use standard library functions such as strtol (string to long), see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol

Answer (score 2):

```
  data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);
```

That line converts the value of `str[i]` to integer value and converts whole number (hence the multiplication by 10). 
E.g.

'0' -> 0
'1' -> 1
E.g."100" -> 100

It assumes ASCII representation and hence uses `48`. A more portable way would be to use `'0'` instead:

```
  data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - '0');
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking here, but in theory having `'0'` won't improve portability much, as it assumes that character set digits `'0'-'9'` are in ascending order next to each other. Which they probably are on any system ever designed, but anyways...

Comment: @user694733 C standard requires '0' to '9' are consecutive and in ascending order. The most commonly used ASCII and less commonly used EBCDIC honor that and any representation that C uses will be required to do that as well if it's to conform to the C standard.

Comment: I didn't know it was actually mentioned in standard. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

For the better understanding print your values that is been generated at the intermediate instance since your not too much experienced in C Program have a `printf` statement so that you can understand the logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
  int top = -1;
  int stack[100];

  /* push the given data into the stack */
  void push (int data) {
    stack[++top] = data;
  }

  /* Pop the top element from the stack */
  int pop () {
    int data;
    if (top == -1)
        return -1;
    data = stack[top];
    stack[top] = 0;
    top--;
    return (data);
  }

  int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i, data = -1, operand1, operand2, result;
    /* Get the postfix expression from the user */
    printf("Enter ur postfix expression:");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            /*
             * if the i/p char is digit, parse
             * character by character to get
             * complete operand
             */
            data = (data == -1) ? 0 : data;
            printf("%d value of str[i] ",str[i]); // returns the ascii value 
            data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);   //multiplies with ten and substracts with 48 so thst u get ur input number
            printf("%d\n",data);       
            continue;
        }

        if (data != -1) {
            /* if the i/p is operand, push it into the stack */
            push(data);
        }

        if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-'
            || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/') {
            /*
             * if the i/p is an operator, pop 2 elements
             * from the stack and apply the operator
             */
            operand2 = pop();
            operand1 = pop();
            if (operand1 == -1 || operand2 == -1)
                break;
            switch (str[i]) {
                case '+':
                    result = operand1 + operand2;
                    /* push the result into the stack */
                    push(result);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = operand1 - operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result = operand1 * operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result = operand1 / operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
            }
        }
        data = -1;
    }
    if (top == 0)
        printf("Output:%d\n", stack[top]);
    else
        printf("u have given wrong postfix expression\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
  }
```

output:[image]